# How to get my app to fill the full height on mobile?

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the screenshot that I took on my iPhone below, the app has a bunch of white space at bottom of the page. This is only happening on mobile. How can I make the page fill the entire screen?

[image]

css:

```
.landing-bg2 {
    background: asset-url("startupstock1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;


}
```

html:

```
    <div class="landing-bg2 size">
   .....contents of webpage
    </div>
```

**Edit!**

I'm able to use the following:

```
.landing-bg2 {
    background: asset-url("startupstock1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

However, I'm then only limited to one BG, if I'd like to have another BG below as your scroll down they just both overlap since they're fixed.. so still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trying move the background to body tag:

```
body{
    background: asset-url("startupstock1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Cheers @Cattla, if I do this the input boxes appear off to the left on mobile for some reason.

Comment: @SonnyBlack try seting `padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px` to the class `.email-input2` . i think the input boxes will be appeared in center. sorry for my english.

Comment: That seems to have worked, only issue is it breaks when adding another background below it.. I wonder how other sites do it. Ah no worries.. seems like most sites have a mobile display page.